# remove all non-alphanumeric characters but allow multi-word terms

Tags: java, mapreduce

For a MapReduce job I'm trying to remove all non-alphanumerical characters, stem the token and lowerCase it if it's not an acronym but I want to allow multi-word terms like "life-changing". This is what I did so far, how should I change it?

```
 String line = value.toString();
        
         StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
         
         while (itr.hasMoreTokens())
         { 
            String token = stem(caseFold(itr.nextToken())); 
            token=token.replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z0-9]*|[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$", "");


             ....
         }
```

Comment: how would you even know if something is an acronym? can you provide a few example of some input and output?

Comment: yes, if word.toUpperCase= word it means it's an acronym. " Three red Apples" will become "three red apples" but BBC will stay BBC

Comment: well ok, I guess that would work for acronyms, but the dash is more tricky. how would you treat `this-is a problem` vs `per-se` or `life-changing`? with human eyes you can make a difference, but not with code...

Comment: well I thought it can just be something in the replaceAll() arguments; like don't split the words if they are separated by - and treat them as a single token

Comment: `this-is-a-problem` would be valid with your explanation above, though.

Comment: yes it would be , so all of them would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Can you use publicly available dictionary APIs such as dictionaryapi.com